# need read-write lock in objective c or c

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, reentrancy, readwritelock

I can't seem to find any read-write locks for Objective C. This is for iphone dev.
Any ideas? The appendix in [this paper](http://www.cs.ru.nl/bachelorscripties/2008/Bernard_van_Gastel___0121363___Reliability_of_a_read-write_lock_implementation.pdf) has some code, but it is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dispatch_barrier_async` function and a concurrent queue to implement a read-write lock.

```
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("your queue name", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // execute read task 1
    });
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // execute read task 2
    });
    dispatch_barrier_async(queue, ^{
        // execute write task 1
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Foundation provides NSLock to help you lock and unlock threads but I think it could help you.

Comment: And `NSRecursiveLock` for recursive locking. Most use cases are easier to implement with recursive locks. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I need a *readers-writer* lock, not just any old lock

Comment: I searched along internet, I think you can only use pthread_rwlock_t and its related commands